# Flutter Xlider - setState - value remains 0 and snaps back

Tags: flutter, setstate

This might be just a simple problem but I can't figure it out somehow right now. I am using the Flutter xslider https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider vertically with values from 0 to 90. When I am dragging the slider it repaints a line depending on the value of the slider and simultaneously it changes the numeric value in a TextField. This once worked but after adding the TextField and updating all the components (Flutter. Dart. Packages. AndroidStudio) I have the following problem:

because of the line `setState(() { });` in `onDragging` the value of the slider always **remains 0 and snaps back after the dragging is finished**. if I leave out the setState method the slider works however my line gets of course not painted. what am I doing wrong? does it has something to do with the surrounding components while building? or is there another reason?

**UPDATE: i found the solution.** I now update the values property by myself such as `values: [sliderValue]` whereas `sliderValue` is a double initialized once and then updated within the `onDragging`. its strange that this is never suggested inside the documentation

````
 body: Column(
            children: [
              new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              ),
              angleTextQuestion,
              new Padding(
                child: Column(children:[ TextField(  controller: txtAngleC,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    double angle = double.parse(text);
                    if(angle >= 0 && angle <= 90) {
                      _angleAirplane = double.parse(text);
                      setState(() {});
                    }
                  },),
                  Text("(type in a value between 0 - 90)")
                ]),
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              ),

              Expanded( child: new Row( children: [
                new Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                Expanded( child: new SizedBox(
                    height: 250,
                    width: 50,
                    child: FlutterSlider(
                values: [0],
                rangeSlider: false,
                max: 90,
                min: 0,
                rtl: true,
                step: FlutterSliderStep(step: 1.0),
                axis: Axis.vertical,
                      tooltip: FlutterSliderTooltip(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                      ),
                onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
                  _angleAirplane = lowerValue;
                  txtAngleC.text = _angleAirplane.toString();
                  setState(() { });
                },
              ))),
                Text(_angleAirplane.toString()),
                new Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                ),
                Expanded( child: new CustomPaint(
                  foregroundPainter: new AnglePainter(
                  angle: _angleAirplane
                )))
              ]
              )),
 ]
        ),
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `values:[0]` to this

```
values: [_angleAirplane]
```

this happens because there is a `setState` inside your `onDragging` method and redraw the slider with 0 value.